# Issue with data manipulate in react with map operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i m some issue with the react setState in react like this

this is my data

```
this.state = {
            _toDoData :  [
                {id:'1', title:'Lang Tag on Hindi', label:'toDo', priority:'Major', ticketId:'ETUIOPS-1', assignee:'Rohit'},
                {id:'2', title:'Template Meta Tag Change about page', label:'readyForDevelopment', priority:'Critical', ticketId:'ETUIOPS-2', assignee:'Rohit Azad'},
                {id:'3', title:'Currency Converter change', label:'inProgress', priority:'Critical', ticketId:'ETUIOPS-3', assignee:'Rohit Malik'},
                {id:'4', title:'SEO Rule change', label:'inQa', priority:'Critical', ticketId:'ETUIOPS-4', assignee:'Rohit Malik'},
                {id:'5', title:'Implement Live tv', label:'live', priority:'Critical', ticketId:'ETUIOPS-5', assignee:'Rohit Malik'}
            ],
            showTodoText : 'Click to show ToDo items',
            showHideToDo:false,
            TO_DO:[],
            READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT:[],
            IN_PROGRESS:[],
            IN_QA:[],
            LIVE:[]
        }
```

and after that i call to this function

```
toDoManupulateData = ()=>{
    let allToDoData = this.state._toDoData;
    let TO_DO = [];
    let READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT = [];
    let IN_PROGRESS = [];
    let IN_QA = [];
    let LIVE = [];
    allToDoData.map((item)=>{
        if(item.label === 'toDo'){
            TO_DO.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'readyForDevelopment'){
            READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'inProgress'){
            IN_PROGRESS.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'inQa'){
            IN_QA.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'live'){
            LIVE.push(item);
        }
        return console.log(item);
    });
    console.log(TO_DO,READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,IN_PROGRESS,IN_QA,LIVE);
    return this.setState({
        TO_DO,READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,IN_PROGRESS,IN_QA,LIVE
    });

}
```

after that  i call to react function like this

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.state)
    this.toDoManupulateData();
    console.log(this.state)
}
```

But my state is blank why can u please guide me.

Comment: Is it correct that you return console.log(item) in allToDoData.map?

Comment: But here to only condition base i m just check data in console log

Comment: Does this { TO_DO, READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT } syntax is supported? Have you tried { TO_DO: TO_DO, READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT: READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT }?

Comment: yes i tried to this but not set state

Answer (score 4):

`setState` is asynchronous. If you want to log the state after updating it, use the second argument callback.

```
return this.setState({
    TO_DO,READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,IN_PROGRESS,IN_QA,LIVE
}, () => console.log(this.state);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your toDoManupulateData should look like this.

```
toDoManupulateData = ()=>{
    let allToDoData = this.state._toDoData;
    let TO_DO = [];
    let READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT = [];
    let IN_PROGRESS = [];
    let IN_QA = [];
    let LIVE = [];
    allToDoData.map((item)=>{
        if(item.label === 'toDo'){
            TO_DO.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'readyForDevelopment'){
            READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'inProgress'){
            IN_PROGRESS.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'inQa'){
            IN_QA.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'live'){
            LIVE.push(item);
        }
    });
    console.log(TO_DO,READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,IN_PROGRESS,IN_QA,LIVE);
    this.setState({
            TO_DO:TO_DO,
            READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT:READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,
            IN_PROGRESS:IN_PROGRESS,
            IN_QA:IN_QA,
            LIVE:LIVE
        },() => console.log(this.state));

}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.state)
    this.toDoManupulateData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think you need to use `map` method, instead use forEach. Also setState is updates the state in async mode, which means setState does not updates the state as soon as it is called. If really want to check there the state got updated pass callback function to setState and check your state there.

```
toDoManupulateData = ()=>{
    let allToDoData = this.state._toDoData;
    let TO_DO = [];
    let READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT = [];
    let IN_PROGRESS = [];
    let IN_QA = [];
    let LIVE = [];
    allToDoData.forEach((item)=>{
        if(item.label === 'toDo'){
            TO_DO.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'readyForDevelopment'){
            READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'inProgress'){
            IN_PROGRESS.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'inQa'){
            IN_QA.push(item);
        }else if(item.label === 'live'){
            LIVE.push(item);
        }
        console.log(item);
    });
    console.log(TO_DO,READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,IN_PROGRESS,IN_QA,LIVE);
    this.setState({
        TO_DO,READY_FOR_DEVELOPEMENT,IN_PROGRESS,IN_QA,LIVE
    }, () => {
       console.log(this.state);
    });
}
```